# Maya work view or day view

Tags: calendar

I am curious in the calendar app instead of always looking at the month view, can I set it to show a week at a time? I have opened dconf and looked around there to see if there was an option to change it but did not see it

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feuture for now but the issue has been drafted: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/maya/+spec/different-views
(cf., https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1073336)